# Access a local method variable inside an anonymous inner class that has a variable with the same name

Tags: java

I have two variables with the same name one in a method and the other one is in an anonymous inner class inside that method. How can I access the method one inside the anonymous class without the need to rename any of them?

```
public void doSomething() {
   final String s = "method string";
   new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         String s = "anonymous inner class string";
         // how can I access the method string here without the need to rename any of the variables
      }
   };
}
```

I know this can be solved by renaming any of the variables, but I'd like to know if there is a smarter way.

Comment: It feels to me like renaming a variable *is* the smart thing to do here - it improves readability aside from anything else.

Comment: you can't access ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to rename any variable then you can create another method to access the `method string` variable. Like this:

```
final String s = "method string";
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        String s = "anonymous inner class string";
        String outerS = getS();
        System.out.println(outerS);
        System.out.println(s);
        // how can I access the method string here without the need to rename any of the variables
    }

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }
};
```

A method getS() is created here to access the `method string` variable.

Comment: I think that OP wants to access to "method String" from anonymous class, But maybe we can do something similar for what OP is looking for.